# Designing menu UIViewController on iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller

I wanted to design a view controller similar to this from the navigation controller class refference. I included the image below **What elements is it made of?** I'm new to iOS but wan't to stick to system firndly approaches

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `UITableview` with the style `UITableViewStyleGrouped`

Check this link 
http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/
http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uitableview-tutorial-grouped-table/

Answer (score 1):

UITableView(Controller) (& StoryBoard).